# What are infinite types?

Tags: haskell, type-theory

Apparently, there is something called an *infinite type* in Haskell.

For example, when I try `iterate concat` on GHCi, I get this:

```
*Main> iterate concat

<interactive>:24:9: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
      Expected type: [a] -> [a]
        Actual type: [[a]] -> [a]
    • In the first argument of ‘iterate’, namely ‘concat’
      In the expression: iterate concat
      In an equation for ‘it’: it = iterate concat
    • Relevant bindings include
        it :: [a] -> [[a]] (bound at <interactive>:24:1)
```

My question is, what exactly are infinite types? How do they fit into type theory and from what resources can I learn about them? Are there any programming languages which allow infinite types?

Answer (score 7):

> Apparently, there is something called an infinite type in Haskell.

Since the Haskell type checker raises a type error every time an infinite type would arise, I would say there are *no* infinite types in Haskell.

Anyway, "infinite" types refer to how many type constructors appear in the type itself. For instance `[[Int]] -> Bool` mentions `[], Bool, Int, (->)`, so it is finite. If we could write `type L = [[[[...]]]]` with infinitely many nestings, we would have an infinite type: a type whose values are lists of lists of lists ... forever.

Infinite types might arise through unification during type inference. If I write

```
let x = [x] in ...
```

then if `T` is the type of `x`, it must also be the type of `[x]` by definition. However, the latter clearly has type `[T]`. Hence, we must solve the equation `T = [T]`, whose solution would lead to the infinite type `L` discussed above.

Haskell, like virtually all programming languages, rejects infinite types since they are often symptoms of a programmer mistake. Further, I guess that adding infinite (regular) types can make type checking much harder. I can't recall any theoretical result about infinite types, but I wouldn't be surprised if type checking would become undecidable.

Comment: I remember seeing some threads on Haskell-cafe some time ago describing how to work with these types computationally, and that the most compelling reason for not including them is error messages become impossible, getting pushed out a level, so you can't find your mistake anymore.

Answer (score 3):

"Infinite" types aren't really part of type theory. In general, Math stays away from dealing with things that "go on forever". Formally, you are looking for the notion of recursive types. Most programming languages *do* support recursive types, but only when guarded by an additional constructor. In Haskell, for example, the following is allowed (in fact, at runtime, it would be equivalent to an infinitely nested list in its representation):

```
newtype InfinitelyNestedList a = Nest [InfinitelyNestedList a]
```

However, there *is* a formalization of this sort of thing that is pretty much exactly what you were talking about: [equirecursive "mu" types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_data_type#Equirecursive_types) (that should give you a good googling starting point). Mixing the list type constructor in, you could think of the infinitely nested list type as

```
µ x. [x]
```

No large popular language that I know of uses equirecursive types and for good reason - it means you no longer have a principal type. In Haskell, every type can be normalized, so if you want to check if two types are equal (in the compiler), normalize them and compare. Here however, you lose that. For example, the following types are all completely equal!

```
µ x. [x]
[[µ x. [x]]]
[[[[[[[µ x. [x]]]]]]]]
```

In this case, the compiler could additionally normalize to the "simplest" first case - but in general there is no notion of "simplest".

Comment: [According to Faxén](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=871905) Haskell does not have the principal type property anyway... although that article is from 2003 and maybe the two issues pointed out there were fixed.

Comment: @Bakuriu Neat! Although that doesn't change the fact that equirecursive types would prevent us from having cheap (in the computational sense) equality over types.

Answer (score 1):

"Infinite types" aren't really a special thing as far as I'm aware. I read this line of the error message:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
```

as just using "infinite" as an adjective to describe a type, not using "infinite type" as a name for a special class of type. The compiler realised that it would need a type satisfying `a ~ [a]` to give a type to your code, and it can't handle such a type.

The error message would be completely correct if it was just:

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the type: a ~ [a]
```

The word infinite is added just to highlight what the problem is. If the type `a` unifies with `[a]`, then it also unifies with `[[a]]`, `[[[a]]]`, etc. It will never unify with any list type nested a finite number of times, since it can always expand `a ~ [a]` one more time.